# Rendering turned out differently comparing with viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

[image]

Greetings,

Basically I have 2 materials assigned to a single mesh.

And then the Green area is supposed to be my Label which i will apply UV Map.

However, in the viewport the green part is exactly what i wanted, but when rendered out, the height has been reduced.

Not sure what I've done wrong here .. ..

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the root cause for this.

I've applied the **Sub Surf modifier**, but did not turned on for Viewport.

Thus during rendering, the sub surf modifier added faces on my mesh and messed up the UV mapping.